# replace < with &lt; within element

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

if a html is

```
<pre>
<img src="imagesrc"></img>
</pre>
```

how would you using jQuery or javascript replace `<` with `&lt;` for anything within `<pre>`
The output for code above should be.

```
<pre>
&lt;img src="imagesrc">&lt;/img>
</pre>
```

Comment: Where are you looking to apply this?  Should the JavaScript work on a string containing this html, or should it apply this change to the current document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying something like this?

HTML:

```
<pre>
<img src="imagesrc"></img>
</pre>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
   var $pre = $('pre');
   $pre.html($pre.html().replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably want [HtmlEncode and HtmlDecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding/1219983#1219983)

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

Comment: For `decode`, I recommend to **not** use jQuery `.html()`. `value` can also contain `<script>alert('evil code')</script>`, which will be executed when setting the `innerHTML` property. See this answer for the `decode` solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it/7394787#7394787

Answer (score 1):

Here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/dzV4t/)

```
$('pre').html(function(){$(this).html().replace('<', '&lt;')});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $pre = $('pre');
for (var i = 0; i < $pre.length; i++) {
  var pattern = $pre[i].innerHTML;
  pattern = pattern.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
  console.log(pattern);
  $pre[i].innerHTML = pattern;
}
```

You can try this if you have multiple pre tags within your document.