# Decoding HTML Decimal encoded character

Tags: javascript, decode

Is there anything embedded in javascript that decodes an entry like `&#34;` to " ?

I would need something similar to what is found here: http://www.hashemian.com/tools/html-url-encode-decode.php (the decimal decode).

Comment: check this link http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-url-decode-encode.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) method. Example:

```
var entity = '&#34;';
var numeric = /\d+/.exec(entity);
var decoded = String.fromCharCode(numeric);
```

A [general HTML entity-to-character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it) method is:

```
var dummy = document.createElement('textarea');
dummy.innerHTML = entity;
var decoded = dummy.value;
```

Comment: I'm receiving something like : System.out.println(&#034;TEXT&#034;); and need to convert it to the readable form.

Comment: @Sergiu Then use the second method. For a single character, the first method is better, but the second one suits better in your case.

Comment: You mean something like: 
var dummy = document.createElement('System.out.println(&#034;TEXT&#034;));

etc ?

This does not work since it complains on invalid characters.

Comment: @Sergiu 1. `document.createElement` should be sticked to the **`textarea`** string. 2. You're missing the closing single quote on your string. Here's a working demo for your given string: http://jsfiddle.net/LGU48/