# string from json is being written as text and not as dom elements

Tags: javascript, json, dom, iframe

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "<div>new div</div>";
```

writes a new div element no problem, however a string from json:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = jsonData.data.children[i].data.media.oembed.html;
```

is always written as text with quotes!

```
 (ie: "<iframe></iframe").
```

yielding:

```
<div id="id">
   "<iframe></iframe>"
</div>
```

and not

```
<div id="id">
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>   //as expected
```

I don't understand why. I want to write this string to el.innerHTML as a string without quotes so it acts like a simple element.

[data from reddit.json](https://www.reddit.com/.json)

sample:

```
html: "&lt;iframe class="embedly-embed" src="//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2FJq9JMm9h9cA%3Ffeature%3Doembed&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJq9JMm9h9cA&amp;image=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FJq9JMm9h9cA%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=youtube" width="600" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;"provider_name: "YouTube"provider_url: "http://www.youtube.com/"thumbnail_height: 360thumbnail_url: "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Jq9JMm9h9cA/hqdefault.jpg"thumbnail_width: 480title: "Good Doggy"type: "video"url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jq9JMm9h9cA"version: "1.0"width: 600__proto__: Objecttype: "youtu.be"__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Are you looking at insert json content to an IFrame?

Comment: @Karthik yes. I have a string from json that represents an iframe conent: I just want to "copy/paste it".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `html` property that you are accessing is XML encoded:

```
"html": "&lt;iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"https://cdn.emb......
```

Note the `&lt;` there at the beginning.

In order to use it as HTML, you'll need to decode it. One way you can do this is to assign it to `.innerHTML`, retrieve it as text, and then assign it to `.innerHTML` again:

```
var el = document.getElementById("id");
el.innerHTML = jsonData.data.children[i].data.media.oembed.html;
el.innerHTML = el.textContent;    // assign it for a second time
```

*Obligatory warning*: Make sure you darn well trust the source of the content you are using here. This opens your site wide up for an XSS attack if the source is untrustworthy.

Comment: works perfectly! thanks!! what is it textContent does exactly? take the "quoted" text and interprets/parses it literally?

Comment: @ApolloCreed [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) returns the text inside an element in its unescaped form. If you had an element in your page like `<p>&amp;&amp;&amp;</p>`, then `pElement.innerHTML` would return `&amp;&amp;&amp;`, but `pElement.textContent` would return `&&&`.