# Is there a way to decode html entities using javascript without there being a document or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html-entities

I'm working in a system where there is no document and no jQuery, but 
I do have to present html entities in an understandable way. So the trick of putting the string in an element and then taking the .text() won't work.

I need a pure JavaScript solution. The system isn't reachable from the outside, there is no user-input so security is not really an issue.

Thanks for any help, I'm out of ideas (not that I had to many to begin with)...

---

Perhaps I should clarify, what I am looking for is a function (or pointers to get me pointing in the right direction) which is able to translate a string with substrings that should translate to characters. So it should be able to translate `"blah &#60; blahblah"` into `"blah < blahblah"`.
There are no additional frameworks I can use other than pure javascript.

***UPDATE:***

I've got the html4 part working, not extremely difficult, but I have been busy with other things. Here's the fiddle:[html4 entities to characters](http://jsfiddle.net/sl4rtyb4rtf4st/b96hxcjb/3/).
You could have done the same with a dictionary with just the characters already in there, but I didn't feel like making such a dictionary. The function is fairly simple but I guess it could do with some refactoring, can't really be bothered at the moment...

Comment: can you show what you have so far

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7394814/791010) has the start of a solution, though it mentions you'll need a hashmap of non-numeric entities to deal with those.

Comment: Yes @JamesThorpe I found that soludion, but most entities I have to deal with are entities like `&euml;`, so then I would have to construct a dictionary with all the possible entities, which is an option but I was hoping/looking for an more elegant solution.

Comment: It would seem that [node html entities github](https://github.com/mdevils/node-html-entities) has files ([html5-entities](https://github.com/mdevils/node-html-entities/blob/master/lib/html5-entities.js)) which make the creation of a suitable dictionary much easier. It will be a beast of a dictionary if I want to include all the html5 entities though. But I think I will be able to get a working function...

Answer (score 1):

This function exists in PHP <del>(htmlspecialchars_decode)</del>.  As such, you'll find a javascript port from [PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars_decode/).  This is based on a very established codebase, and should be better than rolling something on your own.

---

Edit / Add:
Flub on my part.  I didn't read the entities part properly.  You want the equiv of html_entity_decode:

http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using nodejs, cheerio is exactly what you need. I have used it myself a couple of times with great success for off-browser testing of HTML structures returned from servers.

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

The most awesome part is that it uses jQuery API.

Comment: I see... Then your best chance is probably to have a look at this module and just use their approach. There are two arrays in lib/html-entities.js which are exactly what you need, you can build a dictionary from there and use the replace() method on strings.