# Replace unicode characters with characters (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, unicode, unicode-string

Take for example the following string:

`&#8220;A profile of Mr. T, the A Team&#8217;s most well known member.&#8221;`

How do I use javascript replace the unicode character encodings and convert that to the following:

`"A profile of Mr. T, the A Team's most well known member."`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the right way to decode a string that has special HTML entities in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@adeneo posted an option using jQuery. Here's a relevant answer I found that doesn't use jQuery. From this answer: [What's the right way to decode a string that has special HTML entities in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it)

```
function parseHtmlEnteties(str) {
    return str.replace(/&#([0-9]{1,4});/gi, function(match, numStr) {
        var num = parseInt(numStr, 10); // read num as normal number
        return String.fromCharCode(num);
    });
}
```