# How to change html shorthand to html tag when adding content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-html

`var encodedHtml =  "&lt;ol style=&quot;color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: arial, sans-serif;&quot;&gt;&lt;li class=&quot;mod&quot; style=&quot;&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;_oDd&quot; style=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;_Tgc&quot; style=&quot;font-size: 16px;&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;Test data&lt;/b&gt; is &lt;b&gt;data&lt;/b&gt;`

which has been specifically identified for use in `&lt;b&gt;tests&lt;/b&gt;`, typically of a computer program. Some `&lt;b&gt;data&lt;/b&gt;` may be used in a confirmatory way, typically to verify that a given set of input to a given function produces some expected result.`&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;";`

I want to change this content to html tags , so i can add it to some div using js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you sorted out:

[What's the right way to decode a string that has special HTML entities in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it)

A few answers down it has a jQuery version:

```
function htmlDecode(value) {
    return $("<textarea/>").html(value).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var encodedHTML = "`&lt;ol style=&quot;color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: arial, sans-serif;&quot;&gt;&lt;li class=&quot;mod&quot; style=&quot;&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;_oDd&quot; style=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;_Tgc&quot; style=&quot;font-size: 16px;&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;Test data&lt;/b&gt; is &lt;b&gt;data&lt;/b&gt; which has been specifically identified for use in &lt;b&gt;tests&lt;/b&gt;, typically of a computer program. Some &lt;b&gt;data&lt;/b&gt; may be used in a confirmatory way, typically to verify that a given set of input to a given function produces some expected result.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;`";

```
$("<p/>").html(encodedHTML ).text();
```

this also works.