# javascript regex multiple condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a html entities replacement for & that look like this:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
return String(str).replace(/&(?!amp;)/g, '&amp;');
}
```

which are working fine that not to replace the `&amp;` but will replace `&`

how do I add multiple condition to regex of my function so that it will not mess with other html entities like:

```
&apos;
&quot;
&gt;
&lt;
```

i test with:

```
var xxx = "1234 &aaa&amp; aaadas 'xxx' \" kkk <aasd> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx &lt;";

console.log(htmlEntities(xxx));
```

it will replace the `&lt;` to become `&amp;lt;` and this is not what I want, i need it to leave the `&lt;` untouch just like the example `&aaa&amp;` to become `&amp;aaa&amp;`

hope you get what I mean, any idea?

Comment: There are better alternatives than a RegEx (Ask the DOM) E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `|` in a regexp to make alternatives.

```js
var xxx = "1234 &aaa&amp; aaadas 'xxx' \" kkk <aasd> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx &lt;";
console.log(htmlEntities(xxx));

function htmlEntities(str) {
  return String(str).replace(/&(?!(?:amp|apos|gt|lt);)/g, '&amp;');
}
```