# How to use translate service and translate filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angularJS translate directive to translate `self employed` to german like this

```
span(translate="translation_id")
```

and it gives me the following translation `Selbstständig` which is correct.

but when i did the same translation with translate service like below

```
$translate("translation_id").then (translation) ->
  $scope.translation = translation
```

But this time it gives me wrong translation `Selbstst&#228;ndig`.
And the same problem is with translate filter.

The difference between both output is `ä for &#228;`. Why translate service and translate directive is showing different behaviour and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the actual value in your array of translations?

Comment: @S.Baggy The actual value is Selbstständig

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why angular translate directive and angular translate service behaves differently.

but below approach solved my problem.

when using angular translate service, i cannot use returned translations directly. First i have to decode the returned translations like this

```
$translate("translation_id").then (translation) ->
  $scope.translation = translation

$scope.translation = decodeHtml($scope.translation)

decodeHtml = (html) ->
  var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
  txt.innerHTML = html;
  return txt.value;
```

I found the above approach here [What's the right way to decode a string that has special HTML entities in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it)