# How to translate from HTML number to symbol in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have various HTML numbers like

```
&#228; &#240; &#241;
```

I want to convert them to their respective symbols like

```
ä for &#228;
ð for &#240;
ñ for &#241;
```

Is there some way to perform the above operation in javascript or i have to write my own logic.

Comment: put them in an elements innerHTML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it