# Replace all substrings start and end with specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all substrings which start with the `&` character and end with `;`. For example `&quot;`

Will be great if somebody can suggest me how to convert all unicodes.

Comment: Replace with what? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide an example on you have done so far? We can start from that to try to help you.

Comment: `how to convert all unicodes`, you want to convert everything?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it

Comment: Thank you for response. I have tried this regex string.replace("\\&.*?\\;", "");  I have something like this - " &quot;Some&quot "; I expect "Some"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance a `RegExp` object with `&.*?;` expression and the `g` flag then use it to perform replacement with an empty string

```
"&quot;Some&quot;".replace(new RegExp("&.*?;", "g"), "");
```