# How to get all the html inside a tag as it is using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider this for example:

```
<div>
  A&
  <br>
  B
</div>
```

If I use `$('div').html()`, it returns `A&amp;<br>B`. It converts `A&` into `A&amp;` which I do not want.

If use use `$('div').text()`, it returns `A&B`. It ignores the `<br>` which I do not want either.

I'm looking for a way to get all the html inside the div without parsing it and without skipping over the tags like `<br>` either.

This is the result I want: `A&<br>B`. How do I achieve that?

Comment: And what's the problem with `&amp;` ? That would be the correct response to getting the HTML

Comment: That's correct, you should stick to `&amp;`

Comment: I need to get the content as it is. It will be used as input for C++ programs, etc. So I can't have it changed from & to &amp; because the program would give a different output if the input changes from & to &amp;

Comment: This can be done with a little vanilla js. Check out this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7394787/5937428

Comment: @tbirrell answer the question then...

Comment: @Legends - That would just be me copying someone else's work though.

Comment: @Legends If the answer is in another question, it's likely that the question is a duplicate. Please don't suggest that people copy answers.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, then mark it as a duplicate, if it's the same question! You have the reputation to do that.

Comment: As do you. You can click the flag link and mark it as a duplicate as well.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan What actually happens with points received for answers on duplicate questions like the one below? And what happens with the question, will it get deleted?

Comment: From [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates): *Some duplicate questions may eventually be deleted, but often they are left as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical answer to that question.* Reputation points are kept as is.

Comment: Points are kept? This motivates people to copy and post already existing answers as we can see here... Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
    var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
    return textArea.value;
}
console.log(decodeEntities($('div').first().html()))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  A&
  <br>
  B
</div>
```

EDIT

See also `node.innerText`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText

Comment: Thanks. innerText in vanilla javascript like you suggested earlier worked as well. I'll be using that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add it back for reference

Answer (score 2):

This is really a "hack" but it does work.

```
$("<textarea>").html($("div").html()).val()
```