# Convert &lt;p&gt; to <p> and use to format html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-encode

A web service is returning data to my app in this format (unfortunately I have no control over the server output):

```
&lt;p&gt; This is a paragraph &lt;/p&gt;
```

When trying to display this data using `innerHtml` the result is as follows

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

How do I 'pass on' the formatting to the browser so it interprets the paragraph tag and displays it?

Stackoverflow interpreting the `<p>`:

This is a paragraph

---

A plunker to demonstrate https://plnkr.co/edit/BbAVrT8F1rJGZnJmov1g?p=preview, code also listed below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [innerHtml] = "name">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph&lt;/p&gt;`
  }
}
```

I have tried `<script>decodeURI({{name}})</script>` but that simply returns `<"`.

I have also looked at other stack questions and tried a pipe to bypass the security of the html, which didn't work. Reading the Angular2 docs it sounds like that's not it's purpose. I also tried the style override, it failed as this is not a style, it's pure html:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value: string) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the right way to decode a string that has special HTML entities in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7394748)

Comment: It's `innerHTML`

Comment: @Dummy I changed it on the plunker to be `innerHTML`, same result.

Comment: @Siguza I'm working on implementing the `he` library with Angular2, based on the duplicate link.

Comment: Please see my answer to see if it helps

Comment: You also should be aware that it's insecure.

Comment: @zerkms that's why angular turns sanitizers on by default

Comment: @Rots you might be interested in my new edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to decode those entity references, you can have the browser do this for you like in my code example below. Let's assume that `getData()` returns an `Observable` which contains your data

```
.
.
.
class SomeClass ... {
  dataBoundProperty: string;

  someFunction() {
    this.dataService.getData()
            .subscribe(dataStr => {
                let dummyElem = document.createElement('DIV');
                dummyElem.innerHTML = dataStr;
                document.body.appendChild(dummyElem);
                this.dataBoundProperty = dummyElem.textContent; // just grap the decoded string which contains the desired HTML tags
                document.body.removeChild(dummyElem);
            });
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, my data service returns an array of objects, for each object in that array I will need to manipulate a property on the object. Does this work because of the 'double-handling' of `innerHTML` ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by double handling, but if you just assign any string to `innerHTML`, It will treat the string as a html string

Comment: I mean you have used `innerHTML` twice, once to the dummyElem and once when referencing it. If there's no tricks to this, then it won't work - look at the linked plunker above.

Comment: Oh, so  `dummyElem.innerHTML = dataStr;` is to create a sub tree of DOM elements with the `div` at the root, that way when this `dummyElem` is inserted into the document, this subtree is parsed by the browser as html elements, the second `innerHTML` is to obtain this parsed DOM subtree which you can use to insert into somewhere else. Basically we are using the browser to parse your data string into html elements and then extract them into your data bound property so you can use it, not sure if that makes sense

Comment: "Basically we are using the browser to parse your data string into html elements and then extract them into your data bound property" --- why should this be useful?

Comment: @Rots anytime you update an element's `innerHTML` property, the browser has to parse the new value into DOM elements so it can render them correctly

Comment: If so - why not use the string with the target element directly, why use an intermediate element?

Comment: @Rots it is because your data **doesn't** contain **html tags**, it contains **entity references**, if it contained html tags, then you would just bind it to `innerHTML` directly

Comment: Why would `innerHTML` turn entities to a corresponding characters? Any chance you tried your code or it's all based on your assumptions? https://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/ubwLn7bL/

Comment: I have been working an app which fetches markdowned string from server, then process these markdowned strings into html tags, I then just bind it to `innerHTML`, it renders those strings correctly

Comment: I'm sure that other case was somehow different, since what you're trying to do here (and what you explain) makes very little sense from the perspective on how DOM works.

Comment: I am not sure, I might be wrong, you just have to experiment with it

Comment: Well, two things: 1. I'm not the OP 2. I have provided a jsfiddle example that demonstrates that your current answer makes no sense and basically is a no-op. I do understand how DOM works, if you have anything to add, please provide a runnable example that makes sense.

Comment: @zerkms check it again

Comment: Now this is something :-)

Comment: Told you lol, you just gotta experiment, that's what making writing code fun

Comment: I will try this when I figure out how to extract the elements out of the datasource

Comment: @Dummy I made a function that does something similar, i'll post as an answer, but it's really slow!

Comment: @Dummy "Told you lol, you just gotta experiment, that's what making writing code fun" --- well, you posted a nonsense, then it took half an hour for you to realise that and fix. Not sure posting random untested pieces of code aligns with my definition of "fun", it's weird.

Comment: Lol, why tryna argue? You said you understood the DOM, yet you made this statement earlier " 
Why would innerHTML turn entities to a corresponding characters" ?

Answer (score 1):

I created this function based on @Dummy's post. It's inside of the component, and called from the html.

```
export class SomeComponent {
    public dummyElem = document.createElement('DIV');

...

  decode(text: string): string {    
    var ret:string = "";

    this.dummyElem.innerHTML = text;
    document.body.appendChild(this.dummyElem);
    ret = this.dummyElem.textContent; // just grap the decoded string which contains the desired HTML tags
    document.body.removeChild(this.dummyElem);

    return ret;
  }    
}
```

Calling html

```
<div [innerHtml]="decode(object.value)"></div>
```

Doesn't 'feel' very elegant or correct, but it works.

Comment: You should create the element outside of the function so you can reuse it, removing the element from the DOM won't destroy it so, that's optimization for ya

Comment: @Dummy will try it

Comment: @Dummy see the changes above. Performance increase was minimal, but might be significant on a large dataset.

Comment: Another optimization for ya. Append the element outside of your `decode` function, and only remove it when you are done decoding everything, so move the remove statement out of that function too, and only call it once you are done

Comment: @Dummy they receive that from the external API. You're "optimising" something that won't affect the runtime at all.

Comment: @zerkms the OP is decoding the data for each element inside a dataset that might be large, and the code is modifying the DOM each time, tell me why my suggestion isn't an optimization? Won't affect runtime? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Dummy I totally am: every performance optimisation should be preceded with profiling. I prefer to not guess, but measure. Could you please provide the profiling results you're basing your suggestions on?

Comment: @zerkms ok Mr since you insist https://jsfiddle.net/ubwLn7bL/3/ happy? Also, you don't  have to profile something that is obviously slow before making an optimization

Comment: @Dummy now compare with time it takes to perform an API request. I did not ask for an isolated microbenchmark, but for a profile. To profile you take the exact application that implements the exact business case and profile it as a whole. Then you optimise stuff that is slow, not the stuff that is simply easy to optimise. So, nope, I'm not happy that you're continuing spreading meaningless bs here, sorry. I'm not insisting though, everybody is free to turn their code into spaghetty based on anything.

Comment: @zerkms  Calm your little ego, you just over analyzed everything I said, all these flavors and you decided to choose salty. I know you are a genius, no need to let the whole world know. Also, the OP was referring the `decode` function being slow, so your argument is invalid boy

Comment: @Dummy making decisions based on facts is not about being a genius, it's just a common sense: don't do job you don't need to. Your solution consumes more memory. It's not obvious why a memory tradeof is acceptable for you, but cpu tradeof is not. And you made that decision based on... just nothing, you made a random suggestion.

Comment: @zerkms  Tell me why moving the 2 statements that modify the DOM out of the function that gets called repeatedly consumes more memory and cpu time? My suggestion was not random, because the OP said it was slow, hence the proposal

Comment: @Dummy it consumes more memory because you're retaining an object in memory. "because the OP said it was slow" --- where? How do you know it's not the API request that is slow?

Comment: @zerkms  The OP made the comment about it being slow under my answer post third from last. Ok, I agree it has to retain a pointer to that created dummy element which is insignificant, the OP could set it to null after the OP executes `document.body.removeChild`, no big deal. But I still don't see the explanation for why my optimization suggestion consumes more cpu time however.

Comment: I did not say it consumes more CPU. "i'll post as an answer, but it's really slow" --- I already said that, but I really struggle to understand how you people optimise without profiling. Like, really, ... I have no words. I said all I wanted, sorry if sometimes it was rude.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to a The parseFromString() method of the DOMParser interface more details can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)

Whatever framework you r using lets assume that this.value = is a string contains '&ltp&gt' elements.First we need to convert it to a html using new DOMParser() and parseFromString method than we can refer to a document.body.firstChild.data which is a HTML string converted than we can easy add it as a child or use innerHTML to prepand it to a html element.

```
if (this.value && this.value.length) {
        let html = '';
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        let doc = parser.parseFromString(this.value, 'text/html');
        html = doc.body.firstChild.data;
        let target = this.template.querySelector('.converter');
        if (target) {
            target.innerHTML = html;
        }
    }
```