# NodeJS Express how to unescape HTML entities for display purposes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a web application in NodeJS with Express, Angular JS and Google App-Engine Datastore.

I am learning Node. I created a form that "sanitizes" (escapes) user input before inserting into the database. I followed the NodeJS tutorial on the MDN website to create this code:

```
//Trim and escape all inputs
req.sanitize('requester').escape();
req.sanitize('requester').trim();
req.sanitize('dataowner').escape();
req.sanitize('dataowner').trim();
req.sanitize('requested_filepath_list').escape();
req.sanitize('requested_filepath_list').trim();
```

The 'requested_filepath_list' is a list of UNIX file paths.

So when a user submits the request, it is stored in the database in the "Escaped" format.

```
//Escaped data
&#x2F;top&#x2F;example&#x2F;test123.txt
```

Question: How can I "unescape" the data for display purposes?

```
//Desired output
/top/example/test123.txt
```

I tried the unescape function but it does not seem to work, it just returns the same output.

```
let escape_str = '&#x2F;top&#x2F;example&#x2F;test123.txt';
let unescaped_str = unescape(escape_str);
console.log('unescaped_str: ' + unescaped_str);

//Output
unescaped_str: &#x2F;top&#x2F;example&#x2F;test123.txt

//Desired output
/top/example/test123.txt
```

Comment: Why store escaped in the first place,?..  Store inside database as just normal text.

Comment: Interesting point but I thought it was better to store it escaped for security purposes.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to use the 'he' library to achieve this requirement.

Here's a post with the details: [What's the right way to decode a string that has special HTML entities in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it)

Here's the library. I was able to install it using npm install.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/he

Example solution:

```
const he = require('he');

let escape_str = '&#x2F;top&#x2F;example&#x2F;test123.txt';

let unescaped_str = he.decode(escape_str);

console.log('unescaped_str ' + unescaped_str);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :)

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
querystring.unescape(escape_str);
```

Comment: I installed the querystring module and tried those steps, however the string remains unchanged...   const querystring = require('querystring');

  let escape_str = '&#x2F;top&#x2F;example&#x2F;test123.txt';

  let unescaped_str = querystring.unescape(escape_str);

  console.log('unescaped_str ' + unescaped_str);   output &#x2F;top&#x2F;example&#x2F;test123.txt

Comment: Perhaps this only works on Node version 9.0. I am on Node 8.4.0. https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_unescape_str