# Is it possible to ignore &#65279 in innerhtml

Tags: puppeteer

I have a line of code that looks

```
await page.$$eval("a", as => as.find(a => a.innerText.includes("shop")).click());
```

So, it will click at shop and all okay, but if shop is written like this - "S&#65279h&#65279op". So, puppeteer wouldn't be able to find it. Is it possible to ignore &#65279? So, that puppeteer would only see "shop".

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the innerText using DOMParser. Example copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42254787/6161265).

```js
window.getDecodedHTML = function getDecodedHTML(encodedStr) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const dom = parser.parseFromString(
    `<!doctype html><body>${encodedStr}`,
    "text/html"
  );
  return dom.body.textContent;
}
```

Save the above snippet to some file like `script.js` and inject it for easier usage.

```js
await page.evaluate(fs.readFileSync('script.js', 'utf8'));
```

Now you can use it to decode the innerText.

```js
await page.$$eval("a", as => as.find(a => getDecodedHTML(a.innerText).includes("shop")).click());
```

The solution might not be optimal. But it should work out.

Here is [another snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29824550/6161265) for you which doesn't require DOMparser.

```js
window.getDecodedHTML = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
    return String.fromCharCode(dec);
  });
};
```