# Parse / Replace HTML entity characters after JSON Stringify

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have JSON and accessed text in it by using `JSON.stringify`. The example text looks like this:

```
This is a test &#8211; More tests
```

What I want to do is replace the `&#8211` character with the `-` character. This method is fine for one single character but I want to filter out most of the other characters and therefore I don't want to do a hundred if-statements.

How do I do this in JavaScript, is there a way to replace the HTML entity character codes by their actual characters?

Comment: `&#8211;` that's a html entity

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it?lq=1

Comment: Thank you Ajaypayne, I'll try using that.