# How to convert HTML Entity (Hexadecimal) to UTF-16 (two pair hex)

Tags: javascript, react-native, emoji, html-entities, utf-16

How can I convert  html entity `&#x1F60D;` to `\uD83D\uDE0D` in JavaScript? (react native) (emoji )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In react native

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it/7394787#7394787

Comment: @RolandStarke: If it works in React Native, yeah. (I have no idea whether it does.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) library can decode

```
import { decode } from 'he';

decode('&#x1F60D;') // outputs
```

Answer (score -1):

Try String.fromCodePoint(...)

```
String.fromCodePoint(42);       // "*"
String.fromCodePoint(65, 90);   // "AZ"
String.fromCodePoint(0x404);    // "\u0404"
String.fromCodePoint(0x2F804);  // "\uD87E\uDC04"
String.fromCodePoint(194564);   // "\uD87E\uDC04"
String.fromCodePoint(0x1D306, 0x61, 0x1D307) // "\uD834\uDF06a\uD834\uDF07"

String.fromCodePoint('_');      // RangeError
String.fromCodePoint(Infinity); // RangeError
String.fromCodePoint(-1);       // RangeError
String.fromCodePoint(3.14);     // RangeError
String.fromCodePoint(3e-2);     // RangeError
String.fromCodePoint(NaN);      // RangeError
```

[String.fromCodePoint() MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/fromCodePoint)