# How to read ALT Codes using jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, alt

I'm working in a project and I'm facing a problem. I have some client stored in database, lets say one of them is Novák. Now I'm using jQuery (autocomplete), in order to get the clients in the client text field when I want to search. The problem is that, I'm geting **Nov& #225;k** instead of **Novák**. I have searched for an answer but could not find the correct one.

```
<script>
    var availableWorkers = new Array();
    @foreach(var w in selWorkers) {
        var worker = w.fullName;
        @:availableWorkers.push(@worker);
    }
    $(".workerTag").autocomplete({
        source: availableWorkers
    });
</script>
```

So, I think I have to add something here:

```
@:availableWorkers.push(@worker);
```

Thank you. All the best.

Comment: Try to verify that you use UTF-8 as the encoding of your database and your files

Comment: Thank you @Mahmoud for your answer. I figured out a way, I found it useful somewhere here. For all those that have same issue like me, I used this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it?lq=1