# How to decode HTML entities with v-model binding‽

Tags: vue.js, html-entities, v-model

The underused and fairly unknown **interrobang** (**‽**, entity `&#8253`) needs bringing back into fashion! But Vue won't let me use it with my `v-model`.

```
data () {
    return {
        list_name: 'Name&#8253'
   }
}

<input v-model="list_name" type="text">
</input>
```

It's just outputting the value as a string `'Name&#8253'`.  How do we show this amazing symbol‽

Comment: What is preventing you from setting `list_name: 'Name‽'` in the first place?

Comment: You sir are a genius!  lol, dohhhh.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) regarding `v-model`:

> By default, `v-model` on a component uses `value` as the prop and `input` as the event.

As you need an specif behavior, you'll need to have methods to decode (when showing) and to encode (when updating) the value, separating the `v-model` into `:value` and `@input`.

So, your next problem will be just *how to decode and encode HTML entities with JavaScript*. There are some ways already discussed many[<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript) times[<sup>2</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode) here[<sup>3</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it/7394787). I like the [mathiasbynens/he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) library to do it, so here's a sample code showing it in action along with Vue:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      name: 'Name&#8253'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    encode (value) {
      this.name = he.encode(value)
    },

    decode (value) {
      return he.decode(value)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/he@1.2.0/he.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input :value="decode(name)" @input="encode($event.target.value)" />
  <p>{{ name }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed  Erick Petrucelli's suggestion and did the following.

```
VueProjectRoot > npm install he --save
```

Vue Component  file:

```
<template>
    <v-textarea v-model.trim="userNote"
                label="My Notes" outlined dense
                append-outer-icon="mdi-content-save"
                @click:append-outer="saveNote"
                rows="2"
    ></v-textarea>
</template>

<script>
import he from 'he/he/';

export default {
 ...
    data() {
        return {
            userNote: 'I don&#039;t have access to them. &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; onclick=&quot;alert(1)&quot;&gt;&lt;click&lt;/a&gt;',
        }
    },
    methods:{
        decode (value) {
            let decoded = value
            if(value){ decoded = he.decode(value) } ​
            return decoded 
         },
         saveNote(){
             // implement the save action
         }
    }
    ,created(){
    ​   this.userNote = this.decode(this.userNote)
    }
}
</script>
```