# How to convert html5 characters like " &quot; " in opentdb API to normal syntax using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic4

Looking for a way to change `"&quot;hippopotamus&quot; "` using angular pipe or anything related to angular or Ionic 4

i tried this:

```
return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(value)));
```

i got:

```
AnimalPage.html:14 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.



import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'entity'
    })
    export class EntityPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
            return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(value)));
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it/7394787#7394787

Comment: Thanks man!... It worked!... Thanks bro.

Comment: Yes... can i delete it?

Comment: Hey, cool it worked, i think you can.