# Is there any way to remove all lines from a string and put only one line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, google-chrome, browser

I'm trying to inject a string containing HTML elements into a div, but by the way, I only get it if the entire code is on one line.

This is what I am getting when push from the database and try to inject in div
[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfu36.png)

I tried to leave this code on one line and it worked
[This is how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hra1.png)

this is my code:

```
    var html = <%=data.long_description%>
   var html_string = html.replace("\n"," ")
    console.log(html_string)
  var iframe =document.getElementById("descript")
      iframe.innerHTML = html_string
```

The only problem is that I am using innerHTML, as I will not be able to do all this manually.
Does anyone know how
fix/leave all / HTML code in one line?

Comment: The first example is HTML encoded, thus it does not output what you want to. I has nothing to do with the lines or spaces.

Comment: do u know how can I do to inject this html in the div?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it