# Changing Unicode symbols (&quot;) to the equivalent html symbol (")

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, unicode

I am working on a project in react (JavaScript, html) where we make a call to a google search api that returns a title with the content of the search result. currently when we get the results back they are in Unicode for example

```
this isn&#39;t what I want
```

what I would like is for it to be

```
 this isn't what i want
```

I would do a string.replace however there are multiple different codes and I can't account for them all without it being lengthy. any suggestions on how I can change this?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript

Comment: have you tried this solution yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it?lq=1

Comment: That’s not “Unicode”, that’s an *HTML entity*.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create an element, set its HTML content as your encoded string, and then get back its text content.

```js
const encodedResults = 'this isn&#39;t what I want';
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = encodedResults;
const decodedResults = div.textContent; // this isn't what i want
```

---

**Edit:** [@Mr Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716/mr-lister) mentioned that the above method works only when the input doesn't contain actual html tags.

For inputs containing html tags, you can create a textarea, set its content, and then get back its value.

```js
const encodedResults = 'this <i>isn&#39;t</i> what I want';
const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.innerHTML = encodedResults;
const decodedResults = textarea.value; // this <i>isn't</i> what i want
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted :)

Comment: @MrLister You're right,  I edited my answer to include an alternative method which creates a `textarea` instead of a `div`.

Comment: @over-engineer Oh, that's very good; textareas having a PCDATA content model so they don't handle the html tags. Hadn't thought about that, otherwise I'd have posted an answer myself!