# print html entites on DOM in a loop using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var inputvalue = parent.eq(0).children().eq(2).val().length;
var value = "";
for (var i = 0; i < password; i++) {
    var entity = "&#9679;";
    value += entity;
}
parent.eq(0).children().eq(1).text(value);
```

**Error:** it is printing as a string in DOM

Comment: We 100% need a lot more information on this please - What are you trying to print out here?

Comment: You should see this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it

Comment: You're using a method called `.text()`. Why should this method insert HTML? Use `.html()`

Comment: You can replace your loop with `var value = "&#9679;".repeat(password);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting the `text()` when you need to set the `html()`!

```js
var str = '&#9679;&#9679;'
$('.wrong').text(str);
$('.correct').html(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='wrong'></p>
<p class='correct'></p>
```