# How to escape a JSON-data inside the script-tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I want to serve my JSON-data via `script`-tag

```
<?php

  $myArray = array(
    'a' => 'Hello world!', 
    'b' => '</script>',
    'c' => 123.456,
  );

  $myJson = json_encode($myArray);

?>

<script id="mydata" type="application/json"><?=$myJson?></script>
```

and then I want to get back my JSON-data in Javascript:

```
try {

  var myArray = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('mydata').innerHTML);
  console.log(myArray);

} catch(e) {

  console.log(e.message);

}
```

How do I escape `$myJson`-string in PHP to avoid HTML-errors?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve a similar result is to assign the JSON directly to a JS variable,

```html
<script>
var myVariable = JSON.parse('<?php echo $myJson; ?>');
console.log('myVariable', myVariable);
</script>
```

But if you insist on doing it in the way you've mentioned, then you may escape it using [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and then do some dirty hacks mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it/7394787).

```html
<script id="mydata" type="application/json"><?php echo htmlentities($myJson) ; ?></script>

<script>
var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
txt.innerHTML = document.getElementById('mydata').innerHTML;
console.log('Parsed', JSON.parse(txt.value));
</script>
```