# How to check if the special character I'm seeing is indeed what I'm seeing or it's just an HTML entity in disguise?

Tags: javascript, browser, cypher, html-entities, html-encode

I have a div containing a string which is a Cypher query:

```html
<div id="foo">match (n)-[r]-() where n.gid='Cx' return n,r</div>
```

Since the `'` character will be encoded as `&#8217;`, and since Cypher query isn't able to automatically decode it, I need to make sure whether the `'` character I see (and Cypher sees as well) is really the `'` character, not just `&#8217;` but the browser automatically transforms it to `'`.

In all the places the character is always showed as `'`; the only place it's really show its true evil is in the HTML view-source page. I try using a solution from [What's the right way to decode a string that has special HTML entities in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7394748/3416774):

```js
function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
```

But Cypher still doesn't accept it. But I guess I cannot check when the string is still encoded or not, because anywhere I go, the browser will always show the decoded version.

Another problem is when I add this into the console:

```js
string = document.getElementById('foo').innerText
string.includes("'") //false
string.includes("&") //false
```

If it return false in both case, then what exactly the version of the character in there? Is it the decoded or encoded version?

<sub>Related: [Can Cypher interpret HTML character codes as input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70577729/3416774)</sub>

Comment: Why exactly is a plain single-quote character being encoded like that?

Comment: The `<div>` as posted in your question has plain ordinary single-quote characters.

Comment: I have no idea. I copy exactly what's in the script and the output

Comment: If you're copy/pasting from some online resource, then that's your problem. It is not uncommon for that to happen. Just re-type the content manually in your own text editor or IDE.

Comment: No, the input string in the div is typed manually and it should work with Cypher

Comment: Well then the culprit is your own IDE. Single-quote characters have the code `&#39;`. If you're getting something else, then your editor or IDE is putting them there.

Comment: @Pointy you are right. The IDE in here is actually WordPress. I check that and somehow my PHP/WordPress setup decides to convert the characters, and the output of the HTML page is indeed doesn't work with Cypher. Anyway, using the [HTML entity tool](https://mothereff.in/html-entities#match%20%28n%29-%5Br%5D-%28%29%20where%20n.gid%3D%27Cx%27%20return%20n%2Cr) I see that the correct code should be `&#x27;`? Although `&#39;` still works. Are there two versions of HTML entity encoding?

Comment: But anyhow, I guess the main problem still remains: if the string is still encoded, then Cypher won't accept it