# Why is Froala changing my quotes and apostrophe's to code?

Tags: javascript, html, quotes, apostrophe, froala

I am using Froala, and if I type something through the editor like

```
here's
```

..and do an alert on what is returned via the Froala contentChanged function, I get:

```
here&#39;s
```

Why? and how to fix?

Comment: It's just escaping the `'`.  Is this causing an issue anywhere?  It should display as a `'` in your page.

Comment: yes it's a problem,  the client doesn't like the source code being &#39, even though when viewed they properly see  '   here's    '

Comment: @E.D. ask the client if they're willing to have their website hacked instead of using `here&#49;s` in the source code (which doesn't even affect the user in any way). It's a Froala feature that prevents XSS attacks. Other escaped values are `"`, `<`, `>` and `&`.

Answer (score -1):

This is an intentional feature, and not fixable. It is because programs like Froala don't understand values like: ;,'"`!.: ect.

Comment: It's an intentional feature to _escape HTML_ to prevent XSS attacks, not because Froala doesn't understand it.

Comment: Ok, well I ended up using Rob W's response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it/7394787#7394787