# Encode html variable using react

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable that contains html characters.  This variable must be converted to an html safe string.  How do I do this?
Example:

```
data.X="<img src='abc'>";  
//data.X=magicEncoder(data.X)
//Contents of data.X after magicEncoder:
&lt;img&nbsp;src=&#39;abc&#39;&gt;
```

I have tried looking up domPurify without success only to have it strip the html instead of encoding the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a library called: [he (HTML Entities](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he)?

In your example it might look like:

```
data.X = "<img src='abc'>";
const encodedString = he.encode(data.X);
console.log(encodedString);
```

which gives you: `&lt;img src=&#x27;abc&#x27;&gt;`

Let me know how it goes - I haven't used this myself but seems to be a good way to do it. Here's more info from another answer: [Whats the right way to decode a string that has special html entities in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it)

Comment: Worked great! I ran: npm install he.  Then added import {encode} from 'html-entities'; to my file.