# Is there a way to modify the event output rather than re-building it completely with eventContent?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

In v3 of fullCalendar, content with HTML entities was rendered correctly in the browser. With fullCalendar v6, it's displayed as-is:

https://codepen.io/brianhogg/pen/LYqBaWz?editors=001

While I've come up with a hacky way to strip out the HTML entities, it looks like the only way to put the newly formatted title is to rebuild all the output from scratch. For example [using the solution from this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394787):

```
eventContent: function (arg) {
    const txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    const titleElement = document.createElement('div');
    const timeElement = document.createElement('div');
    timeElement.className = 'fc-event-time';
    timeElement.innerHTML = arg.timeText;
    titleElement.className = 'fc-event-title';
    txt.innerHTML = arg.event.title;
    titleElement.innerHTML = txt.value;
    if (arg.event.start.getDate() !== arg.event.end.getDate()) {
        const frameElement = document.createElement('div');
        frameElement.className = 'fc-event-main-frame';
        const titleContainer = document.createElement('div');
        titleContainer.className = 'fc-event-title-container';
        titleElement.className += ' fc-sticky';
        titleContainer.appendChild(titleElement);
        frameElement.appendChild(timeElement);
        frameElement.appendChild(titleContainer);
        return { domNodes: [ frameElement ] };
    }

    return { domNodes: [ timeElement, titleElement ] };
},
```

This feels pretty fragile and I haven't tested it in all fullCalendar v6 views yet.

Is there a way to get the default eventContent and filter it (ie. replace the value in the `.fc-event-title` div)? Or another, cleaner way to replicate the functionality in fullCalendar v3 to output the content with the entity rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [event render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) documentation, the `eventDidMount` callback provides `el` which is a copy of the HTML element being rendered. So this gives you the starting point that I think you're looking for.

Here's a very simple usage example:

```
eventDidMount: function(arg) {
  console.log(arg.el);
  arg.el.innerHTML += "hello";
}
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YzBOwPd

Comment: I totally missed that using `eventDidMount` instead would do the trick. Thanks!