# modify container of event: add HTML after .fc-event-title?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

Would like to modify (not: replace) the information displayed in the fullcalendar timegrid week view. So, show time + title, but also show e.g. the attendees and location (available as extendedProps).

In Fullcalendar v6 I can use [content injection](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection) to completely replace the content.
E.g. `eventContent: { html: '<b>hello</b>' }`.
Time and title (and their classes) will no longer be shown.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563453/is-there-a-way-to-modify-the-event-output-rather-than-re-building-it-completely) refers to using `eventDidMount`.
But this adds HTML outside the existing element.
Would like it to appear after `.fc-event-title`. E.g.

```
eventDidMount: function(arg) {
  console.log(arg.el);
  arg.el.innerHTML += "<b>hello</b>";
}
```

Generates:

```
<a tabindex="0" class="fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event">
  <div class="fc-event-main">
    <div class="fc-event-main-frame">
      <div class="fc-event-time">10:00 - 12:00</div>
      <div class="fc-event-title-container">
        <div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">My title</div>
        <!-- would like the HTML to appear here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- instead of here -->
  <b>hello</b> 
</a>
```

Suggestions how to add extra HTML after the `.fc-event-title` div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the standard JavaScript DOM manipulation functions (which are not specific to fullCalendar) to do whatever you want to anything with or within the HTML element represented by `el`. (The example in the other answer you quoted was intentionally a simplistic one to demonstrate the basic usage of `eventDidMount`, and is described as such.)

Here's an example of using such DOM manipulation functions to perform the specific task you've asked about:

```
eventDidMount: function(args)
{
  args.el.querySelector(".fc-event-title").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<b>Hello</b>");
}
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYxoXzW

Reference material:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element (`args.el` is an instance of this)

Comment: ah of course, I did not connect the dots there. Thanks for the clear and comprehensive answer.